# Magento2 Change Store URL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, store-switcher

I need some urgent help in Magento2. I have a live website say abc.com, and there are around 70 stores. This website was created in cake php.

Now i have converted it in Magento2. Everything is done. But i am facing 1 problem that in the live site, store url is configured like this : abc.com/uae/en , but in M2, the store url is coming is xyz.com/en.

How we can create the Store url like the live site?

Please note that i dont want to convert it in MultiWebsite as migration is completly done store wise.

Can someone help here please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to go check the table `core_config_data`

Inside this table you have many datas, but only some of them contains the informatio you need.

You should have 2 lines for each store

one with path = `web/unsecure_base_url` and the other one with `web/secure/url`

The store url should be contained in the `value` column of the table with these two paths.So all you might have to do is to modify this value.

Comment: Yes but it will allow only store view code, not the store code. like i can modify the value as xyz.com/en where en is the storeview code. But i need like xyz.com/uae/en , where uae can be the store code, and en can be the store view code.